how can I sign a creatTransactionBatch with @safe-global/protocol-kit?
I am using the @safe-global/protocol kit package to execute the creatTransactionBatch. How do I sign and execute the transaction? Is there any example code available

Thanks for your question.
Every SafeTransaction can include multiple transactions. You simply add them to the array of transactions.
Sign batched transactions with the Safe Protocol Kit
Here is how you would create a batched transaction with the Safe Protocol Kit.
const safeTransaction = await protocolKitOwner1.createTransaction({ transactions: [tx1, tx1] })

You could either sign the transaction with a second private key.
Or, if the other signer has the private key on a different machine, you would first get the transaction from the Safe Transaction Service and then sign the SafeTransactionHash.
const pendingTransactions = (await apiKit.getPendingTransactions(safeAddress)).results

// Assumes that the first pending transaction is the transaction you want to confirm
const transaction = pendingTransactions[0]
const safeTxHash = transaction.safeTxHash

const protocolKitOwner2 = await Safe.init({
  provider: RPC_URL,
  signer: OWNER_2_PRIVATE_KEY,
  safeAddress
})

const signature = await protocolKitOwner2.signHash(safeTxHash)
const response = await apiKit.confirmTransaction(safeTxHash, signature.data)

The code is simplified. You can learn more in the guide on [transaction signing].(https://docs.safe.global/sdk/react-hooks/guides/send-transactions#create-a-safe-transaction).
Sign batched transactions with Safe React Hooks
If you use React, you can also use the new Safe React Hooks.
function SendTransaction() {
  const { sendTransaction } = useSendTransaction()

  const sendTransactionParams: SendTransactionVariables = {
    transactions: [tx1, tx2]
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={() => sendTransaction(sendTransactionParams)}>
      Send Transaction
    </button>
  )
}

Read more.
If this answers your question, please mark your question as answered. I am happy to follow up in the comment section otherwise.
